# ASP.NET MVC UIHint does not work correctly when deploy to Azure (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

ASP.NET MVC UIHint does not work correctly when deploy to Azure (IIS).

My model

```
public class AssetModel
{   
    [UIHint("App/UserForms")]
    public int? FormId { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplates folder structure

```
EditorTemplates
-- App
---- UserForms.cshtml ( a dropdownlist)
-- Int32.cshtml (a numeric textbox)
```

In view with AssetModel

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Result (I double checked same published code both cases)

- IIS Express (VS2015 debug + release): FormId displays as DropDownList => OK
- Deploy to local IIS and to Azure: FormId displays as numberic textbox => Not OK

Does anyone know why and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can send a path to the `UIHint`? Try and see if this will work `[UIHint("UserForms")]`

Comment: Yes, UIHint can accept Path. I checked my published folder. I do not know why the file UserForms.cshtml is missing (publishing again does not help). I delete it (in source code) and create a new file. Now it works. It is so weird. Anyway thanks